# What's the best practice when extending an application's template?

Tags: python, django, templates

I've recently started studying Django(ver 1.9), and have a question about  [templates inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance).

Suppose I have a Django project named `mysite` and an app named `myapp`.
And I created base template named `base.html` and another one named `child.html`, which inherits `base.html`.

So directory structure is like this:

```
(project root)
├── mysite
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── ...
├── myapp
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── ...
│   └── templates
│       └── myapp
│          ├── base.html
│          └── child.html
└── manage.py
```

In this situation, I can inherit `base.html` like this.

```
<!-- on top of `child.html` -->
{% extends "myapp/base.html" %}
```

What I'm wondering is, I'm hard-coding the application name.
Are there any other ways of writing that avoid hard-coding the app name?
Or, it's OK and I don't need to worry about?

---

I came up with some workarounds.

1) Place `base.html` directly under `templates` directory

```
├── myapp
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── ...
│   └── templates
│       ├── base.html  # Here!
│       └── myapp
│          └── child.html
```

--> I think it causes file name crashing between applications.

2) Place `base.html` under project `templates` directory
-->In this case I don't want to share `base.html` between applications.
(`base.html` here is only for `myapp`, not other applications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your base template and your child template are specific to your app, so both should live in the same `myapp/` subdirectory. It's entirely acceptable to hard-code the dependency on `myapp/base.html`.

Comment: Thank you @knbk . Finally I thought that it's acceptable because we also have to hard-code the app name in `template_name` in `views.py`. Right?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
|── myapp
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── ...
│   └── templates
│       ├── base.html  # Here!
│       └── child.html
│
```

then use

```
<!-- on top of `child.html` -->
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

Then dynamically changing your Template directory at the beginning of each views.py file.

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS =(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,'myapp/templates').replace('\\','/'),)
```

You will have to do the same for every one of your apps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But I think it's not recommended way. Because if there is another `base.html` in different application, Django cannot distinguish them.
(According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/ , "Template namespacing" admoition)

Comment: How about  dynamically changing your Template directory at the beginning of each views.py file in every one of your applications. `from django.conf import settings`. Then do `settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS =(  os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,'path/to/this/app/templates').replace('\\','/'),)`

Comment: Oh, I didn't come up with such idea. I consider it, thank you